# Why this video won't start playing automatically?

Tags: javascript

Seek time is at 10 secs position, but it won't start playing automatically.
Why? and how can I fix?

My current code is just like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
        this.currentTime = 10;
        this.autoplay = true;
    }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: Why don't you set `autoplay` on the element as soon as possible (e.g., in the HTML markup itself, if possible)? Do you want the element to have no `autoplay` property if it doesn't ever fire a `loadedmetadata` event? That seems unnecessary, since a lack of such an event suggests that video will never play anyway, because it never loads. Alternatively, why aren't you just calling `this.play()`?

Comment: You need to tell us what is in the element with id "video".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("video").addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
     this.currentTime = 10;
     this.play();
}, false);</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! This was it! I will vote it up within 10 mins. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

FYI Some mobile devices do not respect auto play settings for video - iPad, iPhone for example